# Any sortable plugin that allow me to reorder the widgets and save their state?

Tags: javascript, jquery-ui-sortable

I have columns which are DIVs on left and right, I want a plugin or script that allow me to allow sorting and reording the columns between each and every column with specific class for example.

I tried UI.Sortables, It's perfect and easy and I can connect two columns but I have never figured out how to save state for DIVs (It can be done with UL though) but I want a sortable plugin that allows save state for my divs please

I am desperate for this function, can you just suggest me a plugin that has the features I included, thanks in advance

Comment: What do you mean by "save state"? Over what domain or operations?

Comment: I mean save state like storing a cookie, and remembering the widgets order when the user visits site again.

Answer (score 0):

We used this script to store some of our info on the client side, which worked nicely. It might be worth checking out. It does require prototype

http://ajaxian.com/archives/cookiejar-json-cookies